# Wait until a command in su finishes

Tags: android

I am running a `su` process in Android which itself runs the screencap utility (`/system/bin/screencap`) every time the user shakes their phone.

I want to wait for each screencap to finish before I allow the user to take another screencap by shaking the phone. However, using `process.waitFor()` doesn't work for me because I don't want to close the `su` process and reopen it for each screencap (because it would prompt the SuperUser app's toast, which interferes with screencaps)

So far I have:

in service's `onCreate()`:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = p.getOutputStream();
```

in the shake listener handler:

```
if (isReady) {
  isReady = false;
  String cmd = "/system/bin/screencap -p " + nextScreenshotFullPath + "\n";
  os.write(cmd.getBytes("ASCII"));
  os.flush();

  [INSERT MAGIC HERE]
  isReady = true;

  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nextScreenshotFullPath);
  // Do something with bm
}
```

Where [INSERT MAGIC HERE] is what I'm looking for - the piece of code that would wait until `screencap` finishes.

Comment: I'm also open to other suggestions or workarounds - for example I thought about looping to check the file size of the result file (delaying every iteration for 10ms) until the size remains constant, at which point I make the assumption that `screencap` is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way! I echo a single character (say, `0`) using the shell command `echo -n 0` (`-n` to prevent a newline) and then reading it back. The shell won't print the character until after the `screencap` command is finished and the `InputStream#read()` method will block until it can read that character... or in code speak:

in service's onCreate():

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = p.getOutputStream();
is = p.getInputStream(); // ADDED THIS LINE //
```

in the shake listener handler:

```
if (isReady) {
  isReady = false;
  String cmd = "/system/bin/screencap -p " + nextScreenshotFullPath + "\n";
  os.write(cmd.getBytes("ASCII"));
  os.flush();

  // ADDED LINES BELOW //
  cmd = "echo -n 0\n";
  os.write(cmd.getBytes("ASCII"));
  os.flush();
  is.read();
  // ADDED LINES ABOVE //

  isReady = true;

  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nextScreenshotFullPath);
  // Do something with bm
}
```

Comment: of course, this assumes that no other command would output anything to the shell's `stdout` stream (still works if another command outputs anything to the shell's `stderr` stream)

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop until the filesize is constant? You're already forking command line processes :)

If you just want a screen capture, you can do that programatically:

```
//Get a screenshot of the screen
private Bitmap getScreenShot()
{
    View v = findViewById(R.id.your_top_level_layout_or_view);

    //Save the bitmap
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap screenShot = v.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap nonRecyclableScreenShot = screenShot.copy(screenShot.getConfig(), false);

    //Restore everything we changed to get the screenshot
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return nonRecyclableScreenShot;
}
```

Comment: My app captures a screenshot of any app, not just my own (hence the need for root access and the screencap utility)... And looping until the filesize is constant just seems like a really awful hack (although I'll end up doing that if there are no viable alternatives)

Comment: Yes. It is a hack, but no more of a hack thank spawning command line processes :). Since your app is already in the background, you could pull a view id that all apps have: findViewById(android.R.id.content) to get a base view for use in the above screenshot code.