# Java: Wait for subprocess of process to finish before reading process's InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have a process created as follows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su"});
```

In my program, I only want to create this process once. I am developing a root file explorer application for Android, and whenever this process is created, the Android device will prompt the user to grant root permissions. This is a very slow operation, and as this is a file browser, it will need root permissions often. So, I have decided to create this process once and write commands to its OutputStream in the following manner (stdin is this OutputStream):

```
stdin.writeBytes(command + "\n");
```

**Before I can read the output of the command, I need my program to wait until the command written by** `writeBytes` **has terminated.** I have tried `p.waitFor()`, but this causes the program to hang.

Here is how I read bytes from the InputStream:

```
int read;
String out = "";
stdout = p.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[262144];

while (true) {
    read = stdout.read(buffer);
    out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
    if (read < BUFF_LEN) {
        //we have read everything
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that although the `read(buffer)` method blocks until input data is available, it does not block in this case because it thinks it has reached the end of the InputStream.

I have tried to include only relevant portions of my code in this post, but if you would like to take a look at the entire source code of the class where this is contained, see here: http://pastebin.com/t6JdWmQr.

How can I make sure the command has finished running before reading the process' InputStream?

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter similar problem, and I found the answer here:
[Wait until a command in su finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048754/wait-until-a-command-in-su-finishes)

If you don't need any read stream in this shell process, simply add shell read stream may completed the shell process.

Or in XDA also have better way:
[[HowTo]Execute Root Commands and read output](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2226664)